# Custom node in XYData

Tags: charts, javafx-8

I have created my custom chart extending LineChart in javafx. What I want to do is manipulate the nodes used to render the XYData. So I overrided the following:

```
@Override
protected void dataItemAdded(Series<X, Y> series, int itemIndex,
                             Data<X, Y> item) {

    super.dataItemAdded(series, itemIndex, item);
    StackPane itemNode = new StackPane();
    itemNode.prefHeight(0.5);
    itemNode.prefWidth(0.5);             
    item.setNode(itemNode);

    itemNode.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                LOG.info("node clicked");

            }
        });
}
```

but it don't seem to be working. Is the code correct?Could it be that I have set to small height and width?What is the best way to create a transparent (invisible) node but still be able to click on it?

Comment: Why override the method? You can just call [`setNode(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Data.html#setNode-javafx.scene.Node-) directly on the `Data` when you create it.

Comment: :) Although this doesn't answer my question you are correct. I have changed the implementation and lived the override out of my custom chart. The size did have to do with it. Does anybody know if there is a limit on the size of a data node?

Comment: I don't think size matters, but of course if it's too small it's impossible to click. The reason overriding doesn't work is to do with how and when default nodes are added to the data. For example, if you add the data to the series first, and then add the series to the chart, the `dataItemAdded` method is not invoked; you would need to override `seriesAdded` to handle that use case. OTOH if you add the series to the chart, then add the data to the series, your method works fine. This is the general problem with subclasses: you need to know the implementation. "Subclassing beaks encapsulation"

Comment: Yes I did. I had also overridden the `seriesAdded` too. But as I said I changed the implementation so not in need anymore of these functions.

Answer (score 1):

Subclassing `LineChart` is probably a poor choice of approach here. The problem is you need to know exactly how the `LineChart` implementation sets nodes on the data. (Let's just ignore the awful design decision the JavaFX team made here: why does the data have a reference to it's visual node at all? There should be a `Callback<Data<X,Y>, Node> symbolFactory` property belonging to the chart instead.)

It turns out that if you add the series to the chart first, and then add data to the series, for each data point the `dataItemAdded` method is invoked, and so in this use case your approach works:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LineChartClickableDataPoints extends Application {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger("LineChartClickableDataPoints");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis) {
            @Override
            protected void dataItemAdded(Series<Number, Number> series, int itemIndex,
                                         Data<Number, Number> item) {

                super.dataItemAdded(series, itemIndex, item);
                StackPane itemNode = new StackPane();
                itemNode.setPrefHeight(0.5);
                itemNode.setPrefWidth(0.5);             
                item.setNode(itemNode);

                itemNode.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                        @Override
                        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                            LOG.info("node clicked");
                        }
                    });
            }
        };

        Random rng = new Random();
        Series<Number, Number> data = new Series<>();
        chart.getData().add(data);
        data.setName("Data");
        data.getData().addAll(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10)
                .mapToObj(x -> new Data<Number, Number>(x, rng.nextDouble()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(chart);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if you add the data to the series, then add the series to the chart, then `dataItemAdded` is not invoked. For this you would need to override `seriesAdded`. So you can do that, but the deeper problem is you are relying on the implementation of `LineChart`, rather than relying just on its specification. So even if you read through the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/996511a322b7/modules/controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/chart/LineChart.java) and cover all possibilities now, you have no guarantee your code still works if the implementation changes in future releases. In short, ["Inheritance violates encapsulation"](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=28702).

Instead, you can just set the node on the data when you create the data:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LineChartClickableDataPoints extends Application {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger("LineChartClickableDataPoints");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis) ;

        Random rng = new Random();
        Series<Number, Number> data = new Series<>();
        data.setName("Data");
        data.getData().addAll(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10)
                .mapToObj(x -> new Data<Number, Number>(x, rng.nextDouble()))
                .peek(this::addNodeToItem)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        chart.getData().add(data);
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(chart);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void addNodeToItem(Data<Number, Number> item) {
        StackPane itemNode = new StackPane();
        itemNode.setPrefHeight(0.5);
        itemNode.setPrefWidth(0.5);             
        item.setNode(itemNode);

        itemNode.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    LOG.info(String.format("node clicked: [%.2f, %.2f]%n", 
                            item.getXValue().doubleValue(), item.getYValue().doubleValue()));
                }
            });
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This approach works in either case.

As far as I can tell, there's no requirement on the size of the node. Note that the default style sheet applies the following style rule:

```
.chart-symbol { /* solid circle */
    -fx-background-color: CHART_COLOR_1;
    -fx-background-radius: 5px;
    -fx-padding: 5px;
}
```

so, as long as the node has the css applied to it, it will have 5 pixels of padding added to it. You can of course define your own css settings in your external style sheet.

Comment: One last question what is Chart_color_1

Answer (score 0):

Lets say I am adding data to XYChart somehow like below :

```
 XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
 for(int i=0; i<mylList ; i++){
     series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(myList[i].x, myList[i].y));
 }
 LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart =
            new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
 lineChart.getData().addAll(series,series.. ..);
```

The thing is when you add data to a series, the series will automatically create a node. So if you want a custom node or apply any style/CSS to that node you have to create a node first and then set that node to data. Then simply just add data to the series :

```
XYChart.Data data = new XYChart.Data(myList[i].x, myList[i].y);
Node node = new StackPane();
node.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;-fx-padding: 1px;");
data.setNode(node);
series.getData().add(data);
```

So as you have changed the node properties you may want to change the stroke or line color of that series. so after adding all series to linechart :

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.append("-fx-stroke: blue;-fx-stroke-width: 1px;");
lineChart.lookup(".series"+0).setStyle(stringBuilder.toString()); // here 0/1/... is the n'th series addition in the linechart
```